# Drupal navigation not working ajax.js missing

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

We have Drupal 7 site and at some point botom page paging navigation stops working.
After investigating we found that ajax.js missing on those pages.
So when we saved html from our broken page and add ajax.js script then navigation works.

What's the way to add this ajax.js file to all pages?
(We are not Drupal familiar and firm that has developed this site not avilable for this anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it somehow by adding
drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
to module functions

function theme_*_contents($variables){
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
...

I'm still open for improvements for this solution.